# Sending Retrieved Value into a specific page

Tags: php, jquery

I have this jQuery code to show retrieved value into the "result" div. My question is, how to target the result into specified page ?

my code is

```
$(function(){
  // SHOW RECORD
  $('#headmark').change(function(){
    $.post('update_fabrication_data.php',
    {
      action: "show", 
      hm:$('#headmark').val()
    },
    function(res){
      $('#result').html(res);
    });     
  });
});
```

so, my target is to send the result into  inside the updateFabrication.php

Comment: You want to show the result on `updateFabrication.php`? What page is this code running on?

Comment: What do you mean target that on that page?

Comment: @MeLight it is running on getData.php

Comment: i doubt. is this code works? $.post not defined correctly. and where exactly you want to send data?

Comment: @Chriskonz then you should be running this code on `updateFabrication.php` page - unless I am missing something.